# You can't specify target table 'finansal' for update in FROM clause error (!)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

When I execute this

```
DELETE FROM finansal WHERE idfinansal=(SELECT MAX(idfinansal) FROM finansal);
```

I have this error.

```
You can't specify target table 'finansal' for update in FROM clause
```

How do I delete the last record on Workbench?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try wrapping the max subquery in another subquery as a workaround:

```
DELETE
FROM finansal WHERE idfinansal =
    (SELECT max_fin FROM
        (SELECT MAX(idfinansal) AS max_fin FROM finansal) x );
```

This subquery trick forces MySQL to materialize the max subquery before running the actual delete statement.  The same approach can be used for other DML operations, such as update.

Comment: You're awasome.Thanks for help Tim Biegeleisen :)